# PowerShell Script to Update SharePoint Pages library

Tags: powershell

I have yes/no type column with default value is "**Yes** in Pages library.

using PowerShell script I have to change the column default value to **No**

I have 10 pages exist in Pages library.

Suggest some script

Answer (score 4):

There are so many links available on the internet, 
so far the best solution is MSDN article here:

[SharePoint: A Complete Guide to Getting and Setting Fields using PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Yes_No_Field_Boolean)

Though this is MSDN article link, look below for the code example:

```
$SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://SP -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
$SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$SPItem = $SPList.GetItemById("1")
$SPItem = $SPList.Items | Where { $_["Title"] -eq "Item 1" }
$SPItem["yesnofield"] = $false;  
$SPItem.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment $SPAssignment
```

Comment: While link may answer the question, but still it is important to include essential part of the link in answer, because once the link is broken, the answer become useless.. Cheers !!

Answer (score 4):

```
#Load the SharePoint Snapin.
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
##

##
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -f White "Type in web url (ex. http://SITEURL): " -NoNewline 
$webURL = Read-Host
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -f White "Type in list display name (ex. Site Pages, Pages): " -NoNewline 
$listName = Read-Host
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -f White "Yes/no type column name: " -NoNewline 
$columnName = Read-Host

$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    if( $item[$columnName]  -eq $true)
    { 
        $item[$columnName] = $false
        Write-Host "On page:"  $item.DisplayName " column:" $columnName " is set to:" $item[$columnName] -ForegroundColor Cyan
        #Update item#
        #$item.Update();
    }
}
##
```

Remove # on `$item.Update();` to update items